# How to Write answers in simplistic radical form

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I am relatively new to Mathematica and am trying to learn the basics. In the expression below I was trying to simplify a radical equation, but the answer that I am getting is not completely simplified. I was expecting the answer to be $2x^3y^2z^6(5yz)^{1/2}$. Is there any way that I can simplify the expression completely?

```
t = (20*x^6 y^5 z^13)^(1/2)

2 Sqrt[5] Sqrt[x^6 y^5 z^13]

Simplify[t]

2 Sqrt[5] Sqrt[x^6 y^5 z^13]

2 Sqrt[5] Sqrt[x^6 y^5 z^13]"
```

Comment: `FullSimplify[t, Assumptions -> x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0]` will give contracted exponents of $x,y,z$. Your expectation to get $y^2y^{1/2}$ is unusual - why not the simplest $y^{5/2}$?

Comment: Thanks, my expectations were wrong in the first place, and now I got the right answer.